# javascript coding style: multi var declaration

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I'm relatively new to Javascript programming. When reading some code that others have written, I noticed that multiple `var` declaration is grouped together like this:

```
var foo = bla,
    bar = bla,
    foo1,
    bar1;
```

Actually Douglas Crockford also suggest this style on his website. But it looks quite unpleasant to my eye. I would much prefer

```
var foo = bla;
var bar = bla;
var foo1;
var bar1;
```

Besides less typing, is there any reason one would prefer the first style?

Comment: You can use either. If a style helps you and your teammates equally, I would use that style.

Comment: @MarkC.Agreed. In cases like this, where either method works, I would say it's most beneficial to follow the standards of the team for consistency.

Comment: http://danhough.com/blog/single-var-pattern-rant/